# How to extract SSIS package tasks information?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Currently our SSIS 2005 packages are responsible for data loads to databases on our machines (Windows 2008 Enterprise Service Pack 2 64 bit). Team decided to move our databases to a new machine (Windows 2008 Enterprise Service Pack 2 64 bit) and continue running SQL jobs(Executing SSIS packages) on old machine. I started updating configuration files of all the packages to point to new machine. My checkpoint is, some of the packages have hard coded old server names in OLEDB source component. For Ex: Select A.columns, B.columns from OldMachine.Table A join OtherServer.Table B....
My question is, how do I get the source query information where the server name is hard coded from all the packages on old machine(most of the packages are saved as file location) so that I don't have to open them all. Thanks a ton.

Comment: You answered your question yourself. Its Hardcoded!! There's no escaping of opening the packages and changing it. Maybe a good time to make it more dynamic?!?

Answer (score 0):

SSS packages are .dtsx files, basically XML.If you know the name of the old servers and machines you can do a simple text search on the folder where the packages reside. This search will highlight the packages you need to open and amend.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though your answer didn't get me the perfect solution it helped me in the process.